# TCL/TK How to generate comboboxs/buttons in the for loop and call the function?

Tags: tcl, tk-toolkit

I want to generate several comboboxs and buttons in the for loop, and the button command will call the function and check the combobox content, how to get the variable "com$num" and pass to the "get_optimizer" function? How to correct below script? Pls help, thanks!

```
set num 1
foreach SQ {1 2 3 4 5} {
    ttk::combobox $twind.frame.dpcom$num -textvariable com$num -values {Global Definitive Adaptive Cmaes} 
    button $twind.frame.but$num -text "Optimizer Setting" -command [list get_optimizer]
    grid $twind.frame.dpcom$num -row $num -column 0
    grid $twind.frame.but$num   -row $num -column 1
    incr num}

proc get_optimizer {} {
    global [set com$num]
    if {[set com$num]=='Global'} { 
            ...
        } elseif {[set com$num]=='Definitive'} {
            ...
        } elseif {...} {
            ...}
        ...
    }
```

Answer (score 1):

You should pass the *whole* name of the variable into `get_optimizer`, and use `upvar #0` to give that a fixed local alias name inside the procedure.

```
    # backslash-newline for readability only
    button $twind.frame.but$num -text "Optimizer Setting" \
            -command [list get_optimizer com$num]
```

```
proc get_optimizer {varname} {
    upvar #0 $varname theVar
    if {$theVar=='Global'} { 
        ...
    } elseif {$theVar=='Definitive'} {
        ...
    } elseif {...} {
        ...
    }
    ...
}
```

Also, it's more efficient to use the `eq` operator for string equality. And consider whether it would be better to use an array (i.e., `com(1)` instead of `com1`).

Comment: Great! That's really what i want, thank you very much!

Answer (score 0):

Use

```
global com$num
```

(giving you, say, global com1)

instead of

```
global [set com$num]
```

(giving you, say, global Definitive)

Comment: That works... but doesn't do what the questioner wants.